# Saving generated bitmap image as jpg/png image in disk

Tags: asp.net, qr-code

I have a web form in ASP.NET in which a QR code can be generated successfully, but I would like to know if it is able to save that generated (bitmap) image from the browser itself into local disk from codebehind as jpg/png image? And then save that file path into a SQL database. That means without user having to manually right click on the image to save it and so on.

I am currently reading various answers or suggestions on this site and different sources on Google, yet I can't seem to find a solution. Please point me to a solution if there is any

Comment: Yes. Use the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: Is the image ever displayed or loaded into an `<img />` element, or do you only return it from an `.aspx` request? Note that you can also use JavaScript to allow users to save an image to disk as well.

Comment: @Dai I think what i am trying to do now is to return it from an .aspx request, as I am not sure how to use the Content-Disposition method, and it's not loaded into an <img /> element either

Comment: How are you returning a image binary response from an `.aspx` WebForms request? (It is possible, but inadvisable as WebForms loves to interfere with the output, that's why using `.ashx` ("Generic Handler") is preferred for custom binary responses. Also, there are many different ways to return a custom binary response from a WebFoms page request, so I can't help you further without seeing your code so I can see how you're doing it.

Comment: Also, why on earth are you using WebForms in 2021? WebForms has been dead since 2008.

Comment: @Dai I was taught to use WebForms during my classes and I have never learnt .ashx before so I am unsure of how it works, and to explain better, my program works in such a way that the user will create a button to generate a QR code image, which is in bitmap, and that image should be displayed in the web form itself and also that image should be saved as jpg/png into local disk and the file path saved into the database. that's what i am trying to achieve, though i am facing quite a lot of confusion

Comment: You cannot achieve that in an `.aspx` code-behind (e.g. generating an image for display in an `<img />` element, because the image has its own HTTP request that's separate from the request for the page. And I do lament having to tell you, but WebForms is obsolete and dead-end (and has many inherent architectural shortcomings) - and radically different from modern frameworks (like ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core, etc). I strongly suggest you start-over with ASP.NET Core 3.1 if possible.